# Do any editors offer syntax checking when editing bash shell inline in yaml file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Has anyone figured out how to perform syntax checking when you have inline bash shell code inside a pipeline yaml file ?   ...  I typically use the atom editor but willing to use any editor

I am editing azure pipeline template yaml files ( which lives in a different repository than the calling pipeline ) and there is currently no way ( I know of ) to put the bash shell script as a stand alone file ( which would then let editor do syntax checking ) then have pipeline pull it in using  `targetType: filePath` but that is another issue I have with azure

Comment: `Visual Studio Code`. You can install plugins